# Passing agruments to another program in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I am trying to write a script that will parse a directory, find the 3 newest files of a given extension among other files with the same name but different extension and then pass the output to a command line program.

So far I have:

```
$file = dir test -Exclude *.md5 | sort -prop LastWriteTime | select fullname -last 3
\path\program argumentA $file[0] argumentB "argumentC"
\path\program argumentA $file[1] argumentB "argumentC"
\path\program argumentA $file[2] argumentB "argumentC"
```

Not sure if it matters a whole lot but argument2 needs to be in quotes for the program to use it.  I will eventually either have the output written to a file or, preferably use the output in another line of code described in the bonus question.

The problem I am having is that when I use $file[0] as an argument nothing happens.  When I use the file name stored in $file[0] instead of using the variable, it runs, but does not pass argumentB or argumentC.  If I run it from cmd I get the proper output.

My questions are:
How do I get the program to recognize a variable?
How do I get the program to recognize the other arguments?

Bonus question:
The program will output a list of files.  How do I delete everything in the given folder except for the files listed in the output of the program?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean "to pass just one line at a time". You're calling the program three times with 4 arguments per call. Can you be more specific on what you want it to do?

Comment: What do you get when you access `$file[0].FullName` ?

Comment: `$file[0].fullname` and `$file[0]` are the same: `C:\file.txt`

Comment: Thank you.  After looking again, I see what you mean.  It did return output, but did not pass argument C.  Argument B was passed okay.

Comment: What worked was placing the last argument in single quotes.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must of had a special character in it that Powershell was interpreting. By using single quotes you tell Powershell it is a string literal so it should not process any special characters. Check out the quoting rules [man page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315325.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$($file[0])
```

I find that I often have to wrap things in "magical" dollar sign brackets to get them working in PowerShell.

Comment: Nothing magical here. What you have here is [subexpression](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) which just returns the same `System.IO.FileInfo` object in this case.

Comment: Slight correction, it actually it returns a `PSCustomObject`. When I first read arcesso's code I overlooked the end of the first line. However the result of the subexpression is the same, it returns the same object.

Comment: Yes I quoted "magical" for a reason.  It wasn't to suggest that they were -- in fact -- magic, but was rather to suggest that they're a good way to fix things like this that seem to crop up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are piping to `Select-Object` and selecting the `FullName` property you have 3 objects of type `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` with a `FullName` property. You should access the `FullName` property on the object when using it as a command line argument for your program like this:

```
$file = dir test -Exclude *.md5 | sort -prop LastWriteTime | select fullname -last 3
\path\program argumentA $file[0].FullName argumentB "argumentC"
```

If you remove the fullname property from the `Select-Object` cmdlet Powershell will not create a PSCustomObject and you can access all properties and methods from the original `System.IO.FileInfo` object.

This is how you can see the difference:

**PsCustomObject**

```
$file = dir test -Exclude *.md5 | sort -prop LastWriteTime | select fullname -last 3
$file[0] | gm
```

**System.IO.FileInfo**

```
$file = dir test -Exclude *.md5 | sort -prop LastWriteTime | select -last 3
$file[0] | gm
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use a loop with this to avoid duplication. (That way you'll avoid copy-and-paste errors and simplify the problem, especially if you add error-handling or anything else later).

```
$files = dir test -Exclude *.md5 | sort -prop LastWriteTime | 
  select fullname -last 3

foreach ($file in $files) { 
  & \path\program argumentA $file argumentB "argumentC"
}
```

As PS treats collections the same as normal objects anyway, this works even if you only select 1 object.